# How to sort a list compared to an existing list in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a `List<int> allIDs` containing a list of IDs in it's original order. I am creating a element chooser, which lets the user add and remove IDs from this list to another `List<int> selectedIDs`. Now, I have this all up and working, but whenever a user removes and later adds the same element, it's just added to the end of the list (`selectedIDs.Add( id )`).

I want to insert the element to its original position, using `allIDs` as a reference to where it used to be.

Here is some excerpts of the lists to put it all in context:

```
List<int> allIDs = new List<int> {10, 11, 9, 155, 12, 299, 15...};
List<int> selectedIDs = new List<int> { 10, 9, 155, 299, 15... }
```

Now let's say I removed id=299 from the `selectedIDs`-list, for later to try to add it again. How do I insert it between `155` and `15`? I know I can insert wherever in the list with the `list.Insert(obj, index)` method, but how do I do this programmatically in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Do you have any objection to using the [SortedList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx)?

Comment: The lists are obviously not sorted to begin with...

Comment: @JacekGorgoń man, not my day for reading questions. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i've understood your requirement correctly:

```
var ordered = selectedIDs.OrderBy(sID => allIDs.IndexOf(sID));
```

This will order the list of selected ID's by the index of each id in the original, complete list.

Comment: After extensive testing, this works in 9 out of 10 cases. However, some items are still being added to the top of the list, without any kind of sorting applied.

Comment: @KrisSelbekk: If you can reproduce it you should ask a new question, that might be interesting for others too. Can you show an example? Are you sure that the reason is not [LINQ's deferred-execution](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/28/implementing-deferred-execution-and-a-potential-trap-to-avoid.aspx)? You could circumvent easily by calling `ToList()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code :

Look in the 1st list for the index your element.

If this index is 0, add your element at the beginning of the list.

Else index = x;

Take the element with index = x - 1;

If the element with index x - 1 is in your list, add your new element just after.

Else, loop again with the element at index x - 2, if x - 2 >= 0.

You'll finally get the index of the element before that is already contained in the list, and you'll insert your new element at this index + 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead of a List?  The key would be the index, and the value would be the ID.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a `List<MyClass>` rather than a `List<int>`.  MyClass would have two properties, an `int` and `bool shouldDisplay`.  Rather than removing items from the first list you can just mark them as hidden, or not to be displayed.  To un-remove them just set them to be "visible" again.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is really compact and cool, but has a pretty nasty complexity. The following should be faster and more usable on larger lists, although not as compact.

```
public class IdWithFlag
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, IdWithFlag> allIDs = ... // populate somehow, perhaps a custom cast operator would help
```

Now every time you add/remove selected ID, regenerate the other list like that:

```
allIDs[currentlyChangedId].Selected = ... // added or removed?

List<int> selectedIDs = allIDs.Values
    .Where(id => id.Selected)
    .Select(id => id.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Much more complicated, but with better computational complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most efficient answer, but I think it's the easiest one to code:

```
List<int> allIDs = new List<int> { 10, 11, 9, 155, 12, 299, 15 };
List<int> selectedIDs = new List<int> { 299, 10, 9, 15, 11 };

// this will ensure the sort order...
var newSel = (from a in allIDs
    join s in selectedIDs on a equals s
    select a).ToList();

selectedIDs = newSel;
```

The resulting output will always be sorted according to `allIDs` order of numbers.